# Assign to variables from text file

Tags: python-3.x

I have this text:

```
(empty line)
(empty line)
7 -1 -2 
2 -2
(empty line)
-6 2 -5 8
(empty line)
(empty line)
(3, 2), (6,4), 
(2,8), (3,4), (0,6),
(6,6), (7,2)
(empty line)
(empty line)
```

There are occasional empty lines.

What I wrote is

```
with open(txt,encoding='utf8')as f:
    text = f.read().strip()
t = [i.replace(" ", "") for i in text.splitlines() ]
```

it gives me:

```
['7-1-2', '2-2', '', '-62-58', '', '', '(3,2),(6,4),', '(2,8),(3,4),(0,6),', '(6,6),(7,2)']
```

I would like to assign to 3 different variables:

```
d1 = [7,-1,-2,2,-2]
d2 = [-6,2,-5,8]
sets = [(3,2),(6,4),(2,8),(3,4),(0,6),(6,6),(7,2)]
```

Comment: Sorry for my English, how can I improve the question

Comment: Your last section "i would like to assign..." is difficult to understand.

Comment: I did correction to be more clear, I wrote information that is confusing, sorry

Comment: Do you want your d1 and d2 to be integers or strings?

Comment: I need them as integers, Thanks @Babak

Answer (score 2):

Adding to what @DocDriven has done:

```
with open('testt.txt',encoding='utf8')as f:
    text = f.read().strip()
t = [i.split(" ") for i in text.splitlines() if len(i)>0 ]

def findTuple(input):
    input = "".join(["".join(i) for i in input])
    pairs = input.replace("),","|").replace("(","").replace(")","").split("|")
    tuples=[]
    for pair in pairs:
        tuples.append(tuple(map(int,pair.split(","))))
    return tuples

d1 = [list(map(int,i)) for i in  t[:2]]
d2 = [int(i) for i in  t[2]]
sets = findTuple(t[3:])
```

will result in:

```
d1= [[7, -1, -2], [2, -2]]
d2= [-6, 2, -5, 8]
sets= [(3, 2), (6, 4), (2, 8), (3, 4), (0, 6), (6, 6), (7, 2)]
```

Comment: Thank you very much ,but I don't need to sum or subtract the d1 and d2, 
I need to keep them as them are.for example d1 = [7,-1,-2,2,-2] d2 = [-6,2,-5,8]

Comment: Updated the code, but this is a hack not a program.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the most concise solution, but since it is dynamic it provides flexibility and can be easily altered to handle new and/or additional data.

```
# (Already exists)
t = ['7-1-2', '2-2', '', '-62-58', '', '', '(3,2),(6,4),', '(2,8),(3,4),(0,6),', '(6,6),(7,2)']
# ----------------
dataCount = 3 # adjust this according to how many groups of data are expected (if known)

values = ['' for _ in range(dataCount)]
i = 0
for e in lst:
    values[i] = values[i] + e # append the new data to the element
    if e == "" and values[i] != "": # advance to new element but ignore repeat "nulls"
        i = i + 1

# various ways of displaying the data:
print (values)
for e in values:
    print (e)

print (values[0], values[1], values[2])
```

Output:

```
['7-1-22-2', '-62-58', '(3,2),(6,4),(2,8),(3,4),(0,6),(6,6),(7,2)']
7-1-22-2
-62-58
(3,2),(6,4),(2,8),(3,4),(0,6),(6,6),(7,2)
7-1-22-2 -62-58 (3,2),(6,4),(2,8),(3,4),(0,6),(6,6),(7,2)
```

Instead of separate variables, I assigned each group of data to its own list element.

Comment: Thank you @Ctrl S , I will check soon, thanks for the notes

Comment: If you need `d1` and `d2` to be integers, what happens to the `-`?

Comment: It's a negative number,after I need to read each integer to do addition or subtraction ,So i think it will not work in this way, because I need to access each number and tuple

Comment: The problem is to separate the whole number to digits, if all were positive it would be easier , you think is there any efficient way to convert it to d1 = [7,-1,-2,2,-2]
d2 = [-6,2,-5,8]
even if they are strings, it's not important

Comment: Why do you remove spaces in `t = [i.replace(" ", "") for i in text.splitlines() ]`?  Without the spaces, you no longer know where one number ends and the next one begins.  `-6` `2` turns into `-62`...

Comment: you are so right! I should use the spaces to make it how it should be.
but the usage of splitlines() is good?

Comment: Yes, the use of `splitlines()` seems flawless.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (notice that all variables are strings, not list of sets):

```
d1 = "".join(t[:2])
d2 = t[3]
sets = "".join(t[6:])
```

Comment: The problem comes to other inputs, the thing that helps divide d1,d2 and the sets are the spaces. they help you distinguish. Thank you for the try

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for helping me, big thanks to @Ctrl S ,I solved the problem.

```
with open(txt,encoding='utf8')as f:
    text = f.read().strip()
lists = ['','','']
listindex = 0
for i in text.splitlines():
    if i:
        lists[listindex] += i
    if i == "" and lists[listindex] != "":
        listindex += 1
d1,d2,sets = lists
```

to convert the sets to tuples , I just used the eval().